# Not scrolling smooth on UICollectionViewController for large data loading

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I am new to iOS and I'm trying to load data in collectionviewcontroller. Data is loading and scrolling for less data. But scroll get stuck when loading large data. 
But as data in my collection gets increasing, its scrolling becomes rough and after loading some pages, it becomes very hard to scroll up or down. It is getting stuck.

Comment: Can anyone help me on above query?, I have removed AutoLayout feature but scroll lagging is still there?

Comment: just avoid for loops in cellForItemAt method, because it call for each cell when cell appears on view, sort your data on load and in that method just pass values that must be showen

Comment: Why are you reloading your `collectionView` in `cellForItem` method? Delete this line 

        `DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reload `collectionView` in `cellForItem`, delete this part:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }
```

And delete most of those `reloadData` calls that you have there. It's a heavyweight operation - call it only when you really need to reload it - meaning when the data model changes for the whole collection view.

Sidenote:

Don't use `indexPath.row`, but rather `indexPath.item`, `row` is used for `UITableView`s, not for `UICollectionView`s.

Comment: Hi Milan, I removed reload collectionView in cellForItem and it is scrolling fast than prev. But now 1st column data is not reflecting. Other column data are coming.

Comment: @user1531229 this however is not the result of not calling `reloadData` over and over again - but looking at your `cellForItem` implementation - that's such a hardly comprehensible code.. there might be so many bugs there that are hidden in that spaghetti code.. but at least change `indexPath.row` with `indexPath.item` - row is used with tables, not with collections..

Comment: Have changed indexPath.row with collections and no problem in scrolling now. 1st column and scrolling other.  Added in code above.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of cellForItem at indexpath to reload the data . why you are reloading manually in the line?

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
```

Remove above line try to run again..?

Comment: Yes Deep, When I am removing this line indexpath, 1st column data is not reflecting.

Comment: 1st column is fixed  column.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all those `reloadData` calls and try to use `Observers` (`willSet` , `didSet`) in order to load or modify things when a change really occured.

Comment: removed But now 1st column is fixed only vertical scroll and data is not reflecting. Other column data are coming on scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks everyone... Once I removed 
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
```

my issue got resolved. Thanks a lot.